# Mathematical functions for dimension reduction in big data

Tags: machine-learning, dimension-theory-analysis

I need a Mathematical function that can project a high dimensional data set into a low dimensional one.

in fact this topic is very important to me because of my Master thesis's proposal.
All approaches likes PCA,Gaussian random projection and others have been used before, and  i have got confused to what to do!

what kind of functions do you suggest? or what kind of combination of existing methods do you suggest?

Comment: How about nonlinear PCA as described here: http://www.nlpca.org

Comment: A quite general method is to choose a kernel and use [kernel PCA](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2333485/why-use-the-kernel-trick-in-an-svm-as-opposed-to-just-transforming-the-data/2333933#2333933). Then, you can look at neural networks dimensionality reduction and see how you can generalize this idea.

Comment: Since the problem is important to your thesis, I would urge you to give a more detailed problem statement.  If you are reluctant to use principal components (or SVD) to solve the problem  (and this motivates asking for alternatives), it would be helpful to Readers to know better your objections (better than "all approaches ... have been used before").

Comment: @littleO : i have not heard some thing about that. i will check it, thank you :)

Comment: @reuns : it sounds fine. i will search about your idea , thanks a lot :)

Comment: @hardmath : yes you're right. my idea is about "Big data stream classification" . and i have some challenges about this. 
you know, big data is high dimensional and doing classification without  dimension reduction costs too much and won't be good. so the main problem is : how to reduce the dimension of data to prepare it for classification that will be accurate and fast enough in comparison with common approaches? approaches likes PCA,Gaussian random projection have been used  before and it is too hard to improve them. and i don't have enough knowledge in math or data science to handle it.

Comment: If you (and your professor) don't have any mathematical ideas, then looking at the kernel trick and neural network state of art for dimensionality reduction is a good master thesis.

Comment: The singular value decomposition is worth understanding as it will surely be used as a benchmark for any proposed alternative.

Comment: @reuns : it is worth it for more investigation, thanks again :)

Comment: @hardmath : good guidance, but i need a detailed study about singular value decomposition ;)