# What is the difference between a kernel, and kernel (Gram) matrix?

Tags: matrices, machine-learning, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite, python

Given a `kernel`, can we represent it as a `Gram matrix`? For example, a linear kernel can be presented (in Python/MATLAB code) in a Gram matrix as follows: `K = X*X.T`. If this is true, how to represent other non-trivial kernels in their Gram matrix form, e.g., check the following link, `page 5`, `equation 17` showing *Jensen-Shannon kernel*: `K(p,q) = exp(-JS(p||q))`

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3e43/4ca7cbd1869f41e338658f7ab4f954782ad8.pdf

Comment: Can you briefly define (or point me to a definition) of "kernel", as you use the term?  The paper you cite is pretty diffuse, full of examples and not precision.

Comment: You can look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2333933/276986) for the relation between the kernel trick, a Gram matrix (dot product matrix, for a given dataset) and the inner product in a high-dimensional vector space. @kimchilover

Comment: This does not define the define *kernel*.

Comment: @kimchilover In my linked post I explain why (in machine learning) a kernel is any function $k: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for any $x_i \in\mathbb{R}^n, i = 1 \ldots m$, the matrix $K_{ij} = k(x_i,x_j)$ is positive semi-definite.

Comment: Guys, I just want a Python/MATLAB Gram matrix expression for kernel above.

Comment: This is not the good forum. Here we explain the maths behind. See stackoverflow and cs.stackexchange

Comment: So you  are asking, is every positive semi-definite matrix a Gram matrix? Answer: of course.

Answer (score 7):

It seems you are talking about Kernels in the context of machine learning. In which case the difference between the Kernel and the Kernel \ Gram matrix can be understood via the following expression of Mercer's theorem:

#### Mercer's theorem in the context of machine learning

Let $X = \{x^{(1)}, ... , x^{(m)} \}$ be a data set of $m$ points, each of which are $n$ dimensional vectors, i.e. $x^{(i)} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then the function $K$ which maps
$$ K(x^{(i)},x^{(j)}) : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

is a valid Kernel **if and only if** the matrix $G$, called the **Kernel matrix**, or **Gram matrix** is **symmetric, positive semi-definite**.

The matrix $G$ is an $m \times m$ matrix where each entry is the kernel of the corresponding data points.

$$G_{i,j} = K(x^{(i)}, x^{(j)})$$

Furthermore, note that

> A function    $K(x,z)$  is  a   valid   kernel  if  it  corresponds to  an inner    product in some (perhaps    infinite    dimensional)    feature space.

Hence:

For the linear kernel, the Gram matrix is simply the inner product $ G_{i,j} = x^{(i) \ T} x^{(j)}$. For other kernels, it is the inner product in a feature space with feature map $\phi$: i.e. $ G_{i,j} = \phi(x^{(i)})^T \ \phi(x^{(j)})$

#### Sources

Page 18 - https://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/cs229-notes3.pdf

Page 45

- http://svivek.com/teaching/machine-learning/fall2017/slides/svm/kernels.pdf

page 52 - [https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/kernels/0521813972c03_p47-84.pdf](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejordan/kernels/0521813972c03_p47-84.pdf)